# Android collapsing toolbar like Google play games app

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to add a collapsing toolbar in my application like Google play games application. Please help me to implement this.

Here is my layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the link for model: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B96q57CU3elESmpsUFFBcHZaRzA/view?usp=sharing

Link for app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".activity.PlaceDetailsActivity">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/ScrollingAppBarLayoutBehavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:title="Results"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/anchor_point"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/BackDropBottomSheetBehavior">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike"
    app:anchorPoint="@dimen/anchor_point"
    app:behavior_hideable="false">

    <include
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/directions_white_24dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/merged_appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:tag="modal-appbar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/MergedAppBarLayoutBehavior">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/expanded_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/key_binding_default_toolbar_name"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/close_white_24dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please let me know about "app:layout_behavior"

Comment: write the package name dot behavior name in strint or you can write directly  behavior in your xml and do according your need